# $(X_i)_{i=1}^n,(Y_i)_{i=1}^m$ , Show if $\frac{n}{m}\to\lambda$, then $\sqrt{n}(\bar X-\bar Y-(\mu_X-\mu_Y))\to_d N(0,\sigma_X^2+\lambda\sigma_{Y}^2)$

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, convergence

> Assume that $(X_i)_{i=1,...,n},(Y_i)_{i=1,...,m}$ are independent samples of i.i.d random variables. Assume that $E(X_1)=\mu_X,E(Y_1)=\mu_Y, Var(X_1)=\sigma_{X}^2,Var(Y_1)=\sigma_{Y}^2$. Show if $\frac{n}{m}\to\lambda\in(0,\infty)$,

> then $\sqrt{n}(\bar X-\bar Y-(\mu_X-\mu_Y))\to_d N(0,\sigma_X^2+\lambda\sigma_{Y}^2)$

Since $n\neq m$ I realize that using a multivariate $Z_i=(X_i, Y_i)$, and then applying CLT will not work.

I can say using CLT that $\sqrt{n}(\bar X-\mu_X)\to_d N(0,\sigma_{X}^2)$

and that $\sqrt{m}(\bar Y-\mu_Y)\to_d N(0,\sigma_{Y}^2)$

But I can't use Slutsky's theorem to combine them.

Comment: Why do you think $\sqrt{n}(\bar Y-\mu_Y)\to_d N(0,\sigma_{Y}^2)$ when there are $m$ values in the calculation of $\bar Y$?  I would expect to see $m$ or $\lambda$ in that expression

Comment: Write $$\sqrt{n}\left(\bar X - \bar Y - (\mu_X-\mu_Y)\right) = \sqrt{n}\left(\bar X - \mu_X\right) + \sqrt{\lambda}\left[\sqrt{m}\left(\bar Y - \mu_Y\right)\right]$$ and apply the CLT twice.